# Regex to get a URL containing a keyword

Tags: regex, xml, url, atom-feed

Due to redbubble.com's lack of an API, I'm using an ATOM feed to steal information about a user's pictures.

This is what the XML looks like:

```xml
<entry>
  <id>ID</id>
  <published>Date Published</published>
  <updated>Date Updated</updated>
  <link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="http://www.redbubble.com/link/to/post"/>
  <title>Title</title>
  <content type="html">
    Blah blah blah stuff about the image..
    &lt;a href="http://www.redbubble.com/products/configure/config-id"&gt;&lt;img src="http://ih1.redbubble.net/path-to-image" alt="" /&gt;
  </content>
  <author>
  <name>Author Name</name>
  <uri>http://www.redbubble.com/people/author-user-name</uri>
  </author>
  <link type="image/jpeg" rel="enclosure" href="http://ih0.redbubble.net/path-to-the-original-image"/>
  <category term="1"/>
  <category term="2"/>
</entry>
```

Basically using regex... how would I go about getting the `href` property inside the link in the content tag?

One thing we know for sure is it will always have configure in the path i.e. `http://somesite.com/**configure**/id`

So basically I just need to find the URL with configure in and grab the whole thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your awesome answers but my colleague solved it for me!

This is what i ended up using:

```
/http:\/\/([^"\/]*\/)*configure\/([^"]*)/
```

(Ruby regex by the way)

Answer (score 2):

The following regex will extract the href content based on your requirements.  It seems to work for the sample code.

```
href="(\w[^"]+/configure/\w[^"]+)
```

Comment: Why not use lookaheads/lookbehinds?

Comment: @ishpeck - I believe this might be a more efficient search in regex.

Comment: @stema - thanks - you are right.  It is probably better without `\w`

Answer (score 1):

Whatever programming language you're using, don't try to parse the whole thing with a regex. Use an XML parser first to extract the `href="..."`. Then, sure, use a regex to make sure the URL contains `configure`.

As @KARASZI commented, XPath is another good approach.

Comment: Only parse the XML first if performance is really an issue. Otherwise, just go with the regex - it's much simpler to code...

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use regex try this one:

```
href="(?=[^"]*configure)([^"]*)
```

[rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/fVcIefnaEI)

I am using a lookahead to find if it contains configure.